# rviz fails to build because of wrong Python version

Tags: ros, python, rviz, gentoo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to install indigo from source on an amd64 gentoo machine.  The build is failing when trying to build rviz:

```
  ==> Processing catkin package: 'rviz'
    ==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh'
    ==> cmake /opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DSETUPTOOLS_ARG_EXTRA= -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF -G Unix Makefiles in '/opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rviz'
    -- Boost version: 1.55.0
    -- Found the following Boost libraries:
    --   filesystem
    --   program_options
    --   signals
 ==> Processing catkin package: 'rviz'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh'
==> cmake /opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DSETUPTOOLS_ARG_EXTRA= -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF -G Unix Makefiles in '/opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rviz'
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   signals
--   system
--   thread
-- Assimp version has unified headers
-- OGRE_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib64/OGRE
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3.4
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Could NOT find PY_em (missing:  PY_EM) 
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/empy.cmake:29 (message):
  Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
  installing the package 'python-empy'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:147 (include)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:91 (find_package)
    --   system
    --   thread
    -- Assimp version has unified headers
    -- OGRE_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib64/OGRE
    -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz
    -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
    -- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
    -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3.4
    -- Using default Python package layout
    -- Could NOT find PY_em (missing:  PY_EM) 
    CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/empy.cmake:29 (message):
      Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
      installing the package 'python-empy'
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:147 (include)
      /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
      CMakeLists.txt:91 (find_package)
```

The issue I think is that I *do* have python-empy installed, but only for python2.7.  My understanding is that this was the version I wanted to use for ROS anyway, and all the previous packages seemed to find it.  Is there a way to find out why it's trying to use python3.4 or more importantly to tell it to use 2.7?

For what it's worth 2.7 is the system default:

```
maya ~ # eselect python list
Available Python interpreters:
  [1]   python2.7 *
  [2]   python3.3
  [3]   python3.4
maya ~ # python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 25 2014, 06:57:13) 
[GCC 4.8.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Many thanks,
Justin

Update:  Following William's suggestion, I ran:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space ${ROS_INSTALL_PREFIX}/indigo -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DSETUPTOOLS_ARG_EXTRA="" -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python
```

This did the trick -- many thanks William!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213317/rviz-fails-to-build-because-of-wrong-python-version/) by [jdbrody](https://answers.ros.org/users/23117/jdbrody/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is most likely a bug in the Python CMake infrastructure which doesn't respect Gentoo's eselect tool's choice. You can explicitly pass the write Python executable and stuff directly to catkin and that should workaround the issue, similar to this:

https://gist.github.com/mikepurvis/9837958#file-gistfile1-sh-L59

That is for OS X, but it's the same idea. If you want to report it to Gentoo, then you should be able to reproduce by using `cmake --find-package` and show that even though `eselect` has Python2.7 selected, CMake finds Python3.4.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdbrody](https://answers.ros.org/users/23117/jdbrody/) on 2015-07-09**:
Thanks so much  William!  Please excuse the dumb question, but what argument should I pass to cmake --find-package?  It chokes without one and none of the thinkgs I tried seemed right!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-07-09**:
I think it's PythonLibs. After that you have to add more args but it prompts you for those.